# DDD: Always create ValueObject even with all fields null

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, value-objects

### Scenario

The City and Street fields are NOT required on my domain.

I have a ValueObject

```
public class Address : ValueObject
{
     public string City { get; private set; }

     public string Street { get; private set; }

     public Address(string city, string street)
     {
        City = city;
        Street = street;
     }
}
```

I have a Root entity that use the ValueObject

```
public class MyRoot : RootEntity
{
     public string Name { get; private set; }
 
     public Address Address { get; private set; }

     public MyRoot(string name, Address address)
     {
          Name = name;
          Address = address;  // TODO Create with null fields if address is null ?
     }
}
```

### Question

1. Should I create the Address ValueObject if is passed null `new Address(null,null)`?
2. In general there are best practices for the ValueObject creation (always, when requested, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create the Address ValueObject if is passed null new
> Address(null,null)?

No, you should just set the Address property to null on the root object if it does not have an address to be stored.

Your code is fine as it is.